# Stop Upload when a some data already exists

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, file-upload, web-applications

I have an upload button that can upload excel file and save it to my database. What I want to happen is that if there's one or more data in that excel file that already existing the other data will also not be uploaded though it's not yet existing. My code for adding it to the database and upload button are below.

Add to database

```
 private void AddNewTrainee(string strdelname, string strrank, string strcomp, string strcourse, string strcenter, string strinst,
                            string strsdate, string stredate, string strcissued, string strcnumber, string strremark, int recdeleted, string credate, string update, int fromupload)
{
    connection.Open();
    String checkDateAndName = "Select count(*) from Trainees where StartDate= '" + strsdate + "' and Delegate='" + strdelname + "' and REC_DELETED = 0  ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkDateAndName, connection);
    int dataRepeated = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    bool boolDataRepated;
    connection.Close();

    if (!(dataRepeated >= 1))
    {
        boolDataRepated = false;
    }
    else
        boolDataRepated = true;

    connection.Open();
    string certNumber = "Select * from CertID_Table update CertID_Table set CertificateID = CertificateID + 1 from CertID_Table ";
    SqlCommand cmdCert = new SqlCommand(certNumber, connection);

    using (SqlDataReader oReader = cmdCert.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oReader.Read())
        {
            string test1 = oReader["CertificateID"].ToString();
            ViewState["certnumber"] = test1;
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
    strcnumber = (string)ViewState["certnumber"];


        if (boolDataRepated == false)
        {
            string path = "D:\\Intern\\BASSWeb\\SQLCommands\\AddSQL.txt";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
                }
                string sql = sb.ToString();
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delName", strdelname);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rank", strrank);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comp", strcomp);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", strcourse);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@center", strcenter);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instructor", strinst);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", strsdate);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edate", stredate);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cissued", strcissued);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnumber", strcnumber);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remark", strremark);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rdeleted", recdeleted);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdate", credate);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udate", update);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fupload", fromupload);
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                {
                    string msg = "Insert/Update Error:";
                    msg += ex.Message;
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string script = "alert(\"The data already exists\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        }
}
```

Upload Button

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            path = path.Replace(" ", "");
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Datas/") + path);
            String ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Datas/") + path;
            OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + ExcelPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; Persist Security Info = False");
            mycon.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmdX = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", mycon);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmdX.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                delegateName = dr[0].ToString();
                rankPos = dr[1].ToString();
                company = dr[2].ToString();
                courseTitle = dr[3].ToString();
                trainingCenter = dr[4].ToString();
                instructor = dr[5].ToString();
                staDa = DateTime.Parse(dr[6].ToString());
                string startDate = staDa.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                endDa = DateTime.Parse(dr[7].ToString());
                string endDate = endDa.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                certIssued = dr[8].ToString();
                certNum = dr[9].ToString();
                remarks = dr[10].ToString();
                recDeleted = 0;
                dateCreated = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
                dateUpdated = string.Empty;
                fromUpload = 1;
                AddNewTrainee(delegateName, rankPos, company, courseTitle, trainingCenter, instructor, 
                    startDate, endDate, certIssued, certNum, remarks, recDeleted, dateCreated, dateUpdated, fromUpload);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = "alert(\"ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString() + " \");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", errorMessage, true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string errorMessage = "alert(\"ERROR: You have not specified a file \");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", errorMessage, true);
    }
    PopulateData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the transferMode to 'Streamed', otherwise you will always get one file.

Have a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-enable-streaming

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a few things you'll need to tackle to reach your end goal.

1. Use a multiselect method and a get a post list of all files required
   for upload.
2. Do your processing requirements in a [Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. When your done processing, commit or rollback the transaction as necessary and keep the data you want.

Study the link I posted a little bit. At first transaction seem a little bit overwhelming, but they are actually very simple. Maybe I can help you get started in your understandings. There are really only three extra steps;

1.
Initialize a transaction object after you create a command.

```
SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
```

2.
On all of your Sql Commands (Inserts,updates, deletes ect) attach the transaction.

```
cmd.Transaction = transaction;
```

This will allow you to **Execute** the SqlCommands without actually putting them into your database. Lastly, when you've processed all of your inserts and updates you can do the final step. The using statement is not required, just good practice. That could be the next thing you'll want to understand it is very helpful.

3.
Commit all SqlCommands to the database.

```
transaction.Commit();
```

If at any point during your data processing, something goes wrong than you can rollback every transaction like this.

```
transaction.Rollback();
```

Comment: Im beginner in asp.net so im not so familiar with the syntax. Im sorry

Comment: Okay thank you! I'll try this but does this directly will solve my problem?

Comment: It still uploads some file depending on the order of the rows that will be uploaded. What I mean is that if the first row of the file is already existing then it will stop the transaction at the very beginning but if the only existing data is the last row then all the other rows that it has been through will be uploaded except for the last row

Comment: @JMVillaflores Sorry I did not realize that was part of your requirement. The transaction is for an all or nothing situation. Would it be acceptable to just add another function CheckForTrainee to see if it exists before calling AddNewTrainee? If it already exists, you can break out of your while loop in the upload, or skip it and continue.

Comment: Yes, I want do do a cheking first before calling the AddNewTrainee but I dont have any idea of doing that inside the while loop.

Comment: I can try to help you. What constitutes the row already exiting, if the strdelname already exits? On a side note, you should use AddWithValue to scrub your parameters to protect against things like sql injection.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if strdelname and strsdate already exists. Yeah, I use AddWithValue on the AddNewTrainee function when I'm saving the data to database.